# d3 xScale is writing out NaN for values in line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a basic d3 question when trying to apply scaling to a simple line chart. I looked at similar questions but couldn't find any matches.

When commenting out the hard coded x

`//.x(function(d) { return d.game})`

and switching to scaling with

`.x(function(d) { return xScale(d.game);})`

, I'm getting "Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="MNaN,126.82926829268293LNaN,121.95121951219512..." Reading the console, it seems I'm getting NaN for my xScale.

The odd part is the yScale is working fine. I attached the JSFiddle which contains the dataset array I'm using so you can see the structure and my xScale variable.

JS Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mliew21396/98r4gjpz/

Does anyone know what's wrong with my xScale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out brackets `[]` from the `range` array. Use:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([
                  0,
                  30
                ])
                .range([0,w]);
```

Better yet, make it extensible and maintainable and use:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([
                  d3.min(ds, function(d) {return d.game;}),
                  d3.max(ds, function(d) {return d.game;})
                ])
                .range([0,w]);
```

Comment: Oh wow, i feel so dumb. Knew it had to be trivial. Thanks for the help! I'm adding your part now